# How do I obtain an untriangulate rendered image in Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I have an object that is only triangulated in rendered view, so how do i un-triangulate this object for the rendered view?

[image: Un-rendered image]

[image: Rendered image]

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/62977/fix-triangular-lighting-artifacts/62989

Answer (score -1):

Go to edit mode and Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> or Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and select Tris to Quad

Comment: It only removes triangles in the mesh for the unrendered view. But when i render it, it's still the same.